# How to use NSNotificationCenter observers from Delphi?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

Has anyone used the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) class from the Mac APIs from Delphi?
What I need it to add an observer that will notify my app on MacOS when the computer wakes up from sleep (or before it goes to sleep). To do this, there is the method `addObserver` that registers a method to be called for some event. In my case the event is [NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacedidwakenotification).

The code in Swift is something like:

```
func OnWake(notif: NSNotification) {
    // Do something ...
}
.....    
NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(
   self, selector: #selector(OnWake(notif:)),
   name: Notification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidWake, object: nil)
```

I am not sure how to translate the above in Delphi 10.1. The method declaration in `Macapi.Foundation` is

```
procedure addObserver(notificationObserver: Pointer; selector: SEL; name: Pointer; &object: Pointer); cdecl;
```

From the Apple docs it seems that the last param can be nil, but I don't know how to pass the observer pointer, selector and name.

I made a few attempts like the one below, but without success. I either get AVs or there are no errors, but no notifications are received either.
Passing the notification name as NSString causes an AV, so it obviously need something else.
I wonder if the `Self` pointer has any meaning here, because it is a TObject, while I might have to implement the `ILocalObject` and use `GetObjectID` to get an ObjectiveC object pointer.

```
procedure TSomeClass.onWake(aNote: NSNotification); cdecl;
begin
  // Do something
end;
.....
// Inside another TSomeClass method
NSWorkspace.Wrap(TNSWorkspace.OCClass.sharedWorkspace).notificationCenter.
  addObserver(Self, (@onWake), StrToNSStr('NSWorkspaceDidWake'), nil);
```

So, does anyone have an idea how to implement addObserver in Delphi?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a "receiver" class that derives from TOCLocal, and call addObserver like this: addObserver(Receiver.GetObjectID, sel_getUid('onWake:'), StringToID('NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification'), nil). Check the source, for example, in FMX.VirtualKeyboard.iOS. I can provide a complete answer if you need more help

Comment: Thanks. The example in FMX.Virtualkeyboard.iOS was very helpful and will be enough. Especially the `sel_getUid` function that is in Macapi.ObjCRuntime. I will be OK, but if you decide to turn the comment in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Just implemented the observers similar to FMX.Virtualkeyboard.iOS and they work perfectly. The only difference is that I had to add the power event observers to the shared workspace's notification center.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. I'm sure I've actually done this myself at some point, but at present cannot find the code! :-)